# SQL Server 2008 Pivot and Concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, concatenation

Sorry I'm new to SQL so I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following:

I have a table

```
+--------+----------+
|Position|PlayerName|
+--------+----------+
|Forward |Tom       |
+--------+----------+
|Forward |John      |
+--------+----------+
|Center  |Dave      |
+--------+----------+
|Defense |Harry     |
+--------+----------+
|Center  |Bob       |
+--------+----------+
|Defense |James     |
+--------+----------+
|Goalie  |Mike      |
+--------+----------+
|Goalie  |Tim       |
+--------+----------+
```

Result

```
+---------+---------+------------+---------+
|Forward  |Center   |Defense     |Goalie   |
+---------+---------+------------+---------+
|Tom, John|Dave, Bob|Harry, James|Mike, Tim|
+---------+---------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Have you tried to write a query to do this?  You should really show your attempts at solving this problem.

Comment: this is not just a pivot, you are also concatenating the would-be rows.

Comment: Try using sqlfiddle.com for this example -- it will help you and those who are attempting to help you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going to set up a sqlfiddle account to muck around and learn. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result, you will have to do this in two steps.  First, you will need to concatenate all of the `PlayerNames` for each `Position`.  Once you have the list, then you can pivot the data from rows into columns.

Since you are using SQL Server, there are a few different ways to concatenate the data. You can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select t1.position,
  STUFF(
       (SELECT ', ' + t2.PlayerName
        FROM yourtable t2
        where t1.position = t2.position
        FOR XML PATH (''))
        , 1, 1, '')  AS PlayerName
from yourtable t1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af48c/2).  This gets your data into the result:

```
| POSITION |    PLAYERNAME |
|----------|---------------|
|  Forward |     Tom, John |
|   Center |     Dave, Bob |
|  Defense |  Harry, James |
```

Now that your data has been concatenated, then you can convert the data using an aggregate function with a CASE expression or you can use PIVOT.

**Aggregate with CASE**:

```
;with cte as
(
  select t1.position,
    STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + t2.PlayerName
          FROM yourtable t2
          where t1.position = t2.position
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS PlayerNames
  from yourtable t1
)
select 
  max(case when position = 'Forward' then PlayerNames end) Forward,
  max(case when position = 'Center' then PlayerNames end) Center,
  max(case when position = 'Defense' then PlayerNames end) Defense,
  max(case when position = 'Goalie' then PlayerNames end) Goalie
from cte
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af48c/6)

**PIVOT**:

```
;with cte as
(
  select t1.position,
    STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + t2.PlayerName
          FROM yourtable t2
          where t1.position = t2.position
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS PlayerName
  from yourtable t1
)
select Forward, Center, Defense, Goalie
from cte
pivot
(
  max(playername)
  for position in (Forward, Center, Defense, Goalie)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af48c/7).

Both give a result:

```
|    FORWARD |     CENTER |       DEFENSE |     GOALIE |
|------------|------------|---------------|------------|
|  Tom, John |  Dave, Bob |  Harry, James |  Mike, Tim |
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet, I'm reading up on the stuff function right now, thanks for turning me on to that. I've never seen it before. Thanks again for you help. I'm setting up a SQL Fiddle account now as well. Thanks.